# If there are 20 students in a class, in how many ways can a professor give out $4$ A's, $3$ B's ,$4$ C's, and $9$ F's?

Tags: combinatorics

> If there are $20$ students in a class, in how many ways can a professor give out $4$ A's, $3$ B's ,$4$ C's, and $9$ F's?

What I did was use the binomial theorem:

$\frac{20!}{4!\cdot 3!\cdot4! \cdot9!} = 1,939,938,000$

Is this a correct way of approaching a problem like this?

Comment: Your answer is correct.  You correctly used the formula for the [permutations of a multiset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation#Permutations_of_multisets).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

If you want to convince yourself, beyond a hunch that you have remembered the right formula, place the $20$ students into order - $20!$ ways of doing that. Then give the first four an A, the next three a B, and so on.

Because the four A students could come in any order, you have over-counted by a factor of $4!$. Because the three B students could come in any order, you have over-counted by a factor of $3!$. And so on.

Formulae are all very well, but they all look the same sometimes, so it’s good to be able to work the answer out for yourself.